# Show image without delay

Tags: android, image, bitmap, instagram, gallery

I need to implement custom image picker. Something like Instagram.
I have a Grid View with images and when I press image I show big preview. For showing image, I am using custom [**SubsamplingScaleImageView**](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view). Everything works fine.

But it takes about 1 second for the image to appear in ImageView.

Instagram show image immediately. How could I make it as fast as Instagram?

Comment: Are you using any library for loading image?

Comment: I using SubsamplingScaleImageView to show images from Media Storage

Comment: What is your image size.

Comment: @Rasi Can be any size. The same pictures you see in Gallery.

Comment: Even I have used SubsamplingScaleImageView, sometimes its slow. Then I reverted it back to ImageView with Picasso or Glide. Can I know the specific reasons to use SubsamplingScaleImageView ? I guess you need zoom and pinch feature.

Comment: @AsutoshPanda Right. I need zoom. ImageView with Picasso or Glide show it faster?

Comment: I have created this library, this might help you. I used Universal Image Loader to load Image(Replace it with glide/picasso if you want) and then added Zoom feature on ImageView. https://github.com/rahulkapoor1/ZommableLoadingImageView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rasi/loadingimageview/widget/LoadingImageView.java

Comment: Glide is faster than Picasso. And also both will cache the image for you.

Comment: @Rasi I will check thanks.

Comment: @thealeksandr is that worked for you?